# Changing border-color crashes layout in IE9

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-9

I have this strange behaviour in IE9 where, when I change the `border-color` of a `<input>` on  user-input (`:hover` or `:focus`), the layout will get crashed

I wanted to have a form where the labels are on the left with a `min-height` and if the label is wider, then the input field should go in the next row. This works good for me (not in this fiddle for all Firefox though, but on my development, but that's not the problem here)

I tested it in IE9 and then some input fields will jump to the right by the `margin-left` value n mouse hover.

I broke it down, that I can make this unhappen, if I lower the margin-bottom of the label (here from 5px to 4px), but the error shouldn't come up in the first-place

I can also have no error, if I do not change the border-color. Strange!

Here is an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/HerrSerker/9ktvX/ (Check in IE9)

Is this a known bug in IE9? Should I write to Microsoft?

---

### edit

I updated the fiddle.
If I change the border-color via jQuery the bug does not appear.

Comment: Seems to be a combination of things but not specifically the border-color. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9ktvX/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the font size in the input field to px, it fixes it... Seems to be be buggy due to the adaptive units?
http://jsfiddle.net/9ktvX/3/

```
input {
    ...
    font-size: 13px;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid "float" property. You can get the same layout with `display:inline-block;`

Comment: I know about this. But you are not exactly correct. Float left will not render spaces between HTML tags while inline-block will. Unfortunately I don't have that control over the markup, since it's from a CMS module.

Comment: `display: inline-block` doesn't work in older browser versions (<IE9 and <FF3.6 I think).

Comment: @flem inline-block will work in IE7,8 with a hack: `display:inline-block;*zoom:1;*display:inline;`

Comment: @flem Inline-block works in IE8+. In IE7 it only works with native inline elements (no hacks needed)